# Stripping returns and replacing them with commas with Python

Tags: python

I have a text document that I am trying to find the returns and replace them with a comma. I keep getting a syntax error and the the print function at the end is highlighted but I have no idea what is going wrong.

```
orders = []
try:
    with open('vlc.txt') as data:
        for each_line in data:
            try:
                each_line.replace("/n", ",")
                order = order.strip()
                orders.append(order)

            except ValueError:
                pass
with open("vlc_clean.txt","wb") as vlc_file:
    pickle.dump(orders, vlc_file)

except IOError as err:
    print('File Error: ' + str(err))

except pickle.PickleError as perr:
    print('Pickling error: ' + str(perr)

print(orders)
```

Comment: Maybe you want to replace "\n" with "," instead of "/n"

Comment: The code is not indented correctly. Read some python tutorials first.

Comment: Strings are immutable. `.replace()` returns a new string, which you silently ignore. You can't replace things inplace.

Comment: You also forgot a closing paren on the last line.

Comment: You probably meant `order=each_line.replace("\n", ",").strip()`

Comment: Why the three downvotes?  Seems like a perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 6):

Strings are immutable in python, so you must assign the return value of that `replace` operation to some variable:

```
order = each_line.replace("\n", ",").strip()  #use '\n' not '/n'
```

This line is missing a closing `)`, that's why you're getting that `SyntaxError`:

```
except pickle.PickleError as perr:
    print('Pickling error: ' + str(perr))
                                        ^ 
                                        |
                                     missing
```

Answer (score 2):

As I wrote in the comment above you should use "\n" as a new line character and pay attention to your variables.

Here's the working code (I ignored saving as a pickle):

```
orders = []
try:
    with open('vlc.txt') as data:
        for each_line in data:
            try:
                order = each_line.replace("\n", ",").strip()
                orders.append(order)

            except ValueError:
                pass
except:
    pass

print(orders)
```